# Why did the Night King choose this target?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 7 Episode 6 *Beyond the Wall*

> After receiving a letter, Daenerys decide to rescue the Suicide Squad with her three dragons. Sadly, the Night King throws a spear and kill Viserion. But why did he aim a flying, dragonriderless dragon, instead of aiming Drogon, who was on the ground, ready to rescue the whole team, and strongly bound to Dany? It would be easier and have a bigger impact to kill Drogon instead of Viserion.

So why did he choose this target?

Comment: He did try Drogon next, except he missed. It's quite plausible that Viserion was simply the closest.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Drogon was sitting duck and looking elsewhere, Viserion was further away and flying. Only logical target there was Drogon. But since Dany was sitting on it, I guess it had plot armor. They could have had Viserion in Drogon's position to make it logical. But no!

Comment: In any case, Drogon was much closer than Viserion was

Comment: @Keptox, I guess the answer would be "Cus D&D".

Comment: @Aegon agree, what I like in the books (and so on the first seasons of GoT) is the lack of plot armor and plot holes (at least compared to other stuff), the complexity of characters and the fact that nothing is rushed. But this season seems to be the opposite...

Comment: @Keptox, till Season 3, Show was very loyal to books so those were the best seasons. After that, it all went downhill but we can understand why because they knew Martin was tired of, in his own words, laying tracks for a train that was coming with full speed. So they had to make do.

Comment: One is about to escape, the other one is destroying your troops - which one do you prioritize stopping first?

Comment: If the Night King wanted a dragon he could resurrect and ride, then Drogon, who he can see already has Daenerys would be out of the question, since dragons only every allow one rider (barring passengers, it seems).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [I have posted this answer to Movies.SE, which addresses the same topic.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79157/why-did-the-night-king-attack-the-furthest-target-first/79162#79162)

---

You've pointed at a good flaw. Drogon would have been an equally valid target.

But there are some options here as to why the NK chose Viserion over Drogon.

### 1. Drogon is considerably larger.

Although the ice spear did penetrate Viserion's skin with relative ease, Drogon is a considerably larger and stronger dragon.

We don't know much about the ice spear and whether it has any magical qualities that help with killing dragons. But given that Qyburn's ballista would make for an effective weapon too, I'm going to assume that dragon scales can be penetrated by **brute force** alone, without any magic. The ice spear was thrown with a tremendous amount of force.

But maybe killing Drogon was a stretch. He's a bigger dragon, and looks to be more armored as well. Maybe the Night's King wasn't sure that it'd kill Drogon, and therefore he focused on the smaller, weaker dragons first.

### 2. Drogon was on the ground.

Viserion was hit, couldn't fly anymore, and hit the ice with a considerable impact. When Dany flies away later, you can see that the mark Viserion left on the ice is by far the largest, thus showing that Viserion made a high velocity, high impact landing.

Drogon was on the ground. Even if he were to be hit in the same fashion as Viserion, he wouldn't hit the ground with such an impact, thus not knocking him out or killing him on impact. This may give Drogon (or Danaerys) the time to deal with the spear.
Viserion did lose a lot of blood very quickly; but Drogon is comparatively larger and more armored, would bleed less, and is maybe able to shrug it off more easily (similar to why stabbing a dog-sized animal with a dagger will kill it, but stabbing an elephant-sized animal will only wound it)

> **edit**
>   There is another thing to consider here. The spear hit Viserion **under the wing**. I'm not sure how much of a marksman the Night's King is, but he hit Viserion in a place that would prevent him from flying, which is exactly how he should have taken Viserion down. It's also likely that the dragons are less armored near their wings, because armoring would chafe them during flying. They need a fair range of movement with their wings.
>
> This is pure speculation, but if we assume that the Night's King was aiming for a weak spot near the base of the wing, Drogon would not be a viable target as he was using his wings to rest on the ground, and therefore covering it. The weak spot would not be visible/hittable by the Night's King.
>   Even if he could pierce Drogon's wing to hit the weak spot anyway, he had no line of sight to the weak spot and would be guesstimating his throw. Since this theory assumes that the Night's King was aiming precisely, that makes Drogon a difficult target to accurately hit (exactly on the weak spot).
>   Comparatively, the flying dragons were better targets, as their weak spots are more exposed to those below them.
>
> [Looking at the linked image in GhotiandChips' answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWPxZ.jpg), from the Night's King's perspective, most of what he could hit on Drogon seems to either be pretty well armored, or invisible due to the wing covering line of sight to it.

### 3. Drogon couldn't escape right away.

It should have been clear to the Night's King that Drogon was the transport dragon, carrying Dany and soon also the others. This slows Drogon down. He is also not able to just up and leave, because he can't leave Dany or the others, who will be quickly overwhelmed by the wights.

The Night's King wasn't trying to kill one dragon, he was trying to kill **multiple** dragons. He obviously did not stop at killing one. Though we didn't see him throw a third spear, nor target Rhaegal specifically, it seems fair to assume that he was trying to kill all the dragons.

**If he kills Drogon first**, Rhaegal and Viserion can immediately fly away. They are already in the air, mobile, and they don't have to take people along with them.
**If he kills a flying dragon first**, Drogon can't just fly away. Not only will it take him more time to leave (due to not flying already), he also needs to load people, and presumably fly more safely so that the people do not fall off (evidenced by Jorah almost falling off when Drogon dodged the spear).

If you're trying to kill as much as you can, start by killing those who can run away to safety quickly, and kill the slow ones later.

### 4. Unknown and out of universe reasons

- Viserion was the weakest dragon, mentally and physically. Maybe that's why Viserion was targeted. Maybe dragons can resist the resurrection of the white walkers (or retain their identity), but Viserion is notably weak (as was Vyserys, who the dragon is named after). But this is pure speculation of course.
- **It's a story**. It wouldn't make narrative sense to kill the representative dragon first. Drogon is shown considerably more often than the others, because he is the representative of the dragons. This is similar to Thormund. We haven't seen any wildlings (excuse me, **Free Folk**) lately. Whenever the wildl... Free Folk have been part of the story, they have been represented by Thormund. Other representatives are Grey Worm (for the Unsullied), Daario (for the Second Sons), Yohn Royce (for the knights of the Vale), Jaqen (for the Faceless Men, who really should be represented by many faces to prove a point), ...
- It's classic exposition. When a villain introduces his doomsday weapon, he will usually showcase its ability on a random test subject. This is done to **prove to the viewer** that the weapon is real and deadly. I could point to another example from Rick and Morty. There is a scene where Rick is sad, but is not speaking (it's just music playing). He takes out a device, and a little creature, and kills the creature with the device. He then puts the device on his own head, clearly intending to kill himself. **If the viewer did not see the first creature die, they would not understand that this is a suicide attempt** (e.g. maybe it's a device to clear headaches). The same is true here. Viserion's death proves to the viewer that **dragons can be killed by White Walkers**. Up until now, that was never proven. It's possible that viewers thought that the dragons are the be all end all solution to White Walkers, but this scene proves that they are still risking their lives by fighting the White Walkers.

Comment: My money is on he chose Viserion because he was most likely to not wear plot armor.

Comment: @user1129682: That is not an answer in regards to the Night's King's _reasoning_ though. He did not think "I shall kill the one that isn't narratively important". Narrative reasons can exist (hence why I added 4. to my answer), but I feel that "plot armor" is a lazy excuse to not look for actual in-universe reasons. Plot armor only applies when there is no in-universe reason, and that isn't definitively the case (which is what I explore in points 1. 2. and 3.). The OP's question would remain valid if we swap Drogon for Rhaegal (in the scene itself), which eliminates the plot armor option.

Comment: The Night King is about to break the Wall. Why not the fourth wall along the way? I am much more intrigued by how slow he is. After nailing Viserion there was ample time to just pick another spear from his horse, which was standing right next to him and just hurl it at the big dragon sitting right in front of him. But for some reason it takes him like 10 Minutes to walk these 5 steps and grab the spear that is already there and ready to go.

Comment: @user1129682 Your witticisms aren't adding to the discussion. You're trying to shut down a meaningful conversation by calling out a lack of writing quality with no evidence other than cynicism. As to the timing between the spears, consider that immortal beings are usually not in a hurry (as their time is not limited), and that [time dilation is a well established trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeDilation). E.g. characters manage to have a 2 minute conversation during a timebomb that has 1 minute on the clock; or people getting the message from a phone call very quickly.

Comment: @user1129682: The Night's King has _consistently_ been shown to not be in a hurry. He operates under the idea that "slow and steady wins the race". Which makes sense for an immortal being; Lord Elrond seemed similarly unhurried through much of the LOTR plot. The Night's King being slow could be relevant in-universe (Walkers are simply that slow due to their nature), or it could be out of universe (telegraphing his methodical and intelligent nature to the viewers), but regardless of _why_ he is slow, **his character is at least consistent**. All walkers (not wights) have been slow-moving so far

Comment: Of course they are not. [This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) This question is dancing on the edge of a "good subjective question" and comes very close to receiving my close vote for "primarily oppinion based" because we know close to nothing about the Night King and therefore cannot judge on his reasoning.

Comment: @user1129682: "unspoken" is not the same as "unprovable" or "undiscussable". Similarly, a question like "Why does Jon stop Davos from talking about his resurrection to Dany?" is allowed, even though his reasoning has not been **explicitly** discussed in the show. It's a fair question that can receive a proper answer based on what the show(/books) has presented. If your interpretation of the rules is correct, **every** question posted here should be answerable by a copy/pasted quote from the source material, and implicit reasoning would be disallowed; which is simply not the case.

Comment: @user1129682: Also, if this is not a discussion board, then your witticisms and pseudo-input are even more pointless, since you're not focusing on the question at hand but merely adding tangential cynicism to an answer that otherwise tries to focus on the source material and common sense.

Comment: I am also not answering the question. I am just commenting and this is not a discussion board. You should read the meta sections. Ever SE flavor has a couple of topics trying to grasp hard rules by which posts can and should be flagged this way or another. In essence, everybody eventually agrees a little bit, that you can best tell by the answers if a question is good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any tactical/strategical decision made by the show Walkers has made sense so far.

> The Night King could have easily thrown both spears at the party long before any dragons arrived, for starters.

So, **out-of-universe explanation**: The White Walkers are purely plot elements by now, not independent characters that actually make sense. Don't think too much about them.

If you really want to come up with an **in-universe explanation** to make it feel better:

> Maybe he aimed his first shot at Viserion because the two riderless dragons where about to toast his army and he prioritized saving soldiers (which presumable take a while to "recruit", as he has spent 7 seasons on this project by now. (Doesn't stop him to let them zerg-rush the heroes in really dumb ways, of course)). Also, dragons in the air can escape his range more easily than a dragon on the ground, and he wanted to be thorough. If Drogon didn't take off without the boarding being completed, maybe he would have taken the time to aim at Rhaegal next, too. But he didn't expect that the heroes would leave Jon behind, so he had to change plans and fire at Drogon immediately.

Comment: I saw this reasoning on the [Movies&TV version of this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79159/42655), but, as I mention on *that* post, this idea that Drogon just sat there while the other two dragons burned his army is **false** - he is seen [continually breathing fire on the army, even up until the moment the Night King takes aim](http://imgur.com/a/MVdKy) - Viserion and Drogon are breathing fire on the army at the same time when the spear is thrown, and Drogon arguably did more damage.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Well, you have a point. Then the "he has a longer escape time" part is the only thread left to cover this plot hole.

Comment: You may be surprised. There are *some* semi-decent points, which, together, make a decent counter-argument. To summarise: Viserion was in the air (he doesn't die until he hits the ground - the spear would probably severely wound a grounded dragon, but it's the impact that would kill one. The Night King specifically chose a flying one for this reason), plus he thought he'd get the hard shot out of the way and aim for Drogon next to take out multiple dragons in one fell swoop.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - I agree. It seemed clear to me that the Night King wanted to ensure that he got a dragon minion.